# Chart returns different results depending on size of range

Tags: vba, excel, charts, excel-2007

I try to make program in macro-excel that show chart of dec 2012- curent month data.

I want X-axis is the month, but only in january, the axis n the legend switched.

My code:

```
Public Sub pi()

    Dim bulan1
    Dim bulan2
    Dim kpi As Worksheet
    Dim data As Worksheet
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim xaxis As Axis


    Set kpi = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("KPI chart")
    Set data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")

    bulan1 = Month(Now)

    For a = 2 To 14
        bulan2 = Month(Cells(54, a).Value)

        If bulan2 = bulan1 Then 

        End If
    Next

    kpi.ChartObjects("Chart 16").Activate
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(data.Cells(54, 1), data.Cells(57, a))

End Sub
```

Picture :
http://melegenda.tumblr.com/image/72825632452

I think I missed something?
(I use excel 2007)

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007443) may help you.

Comment: that helps. but not for this question :)

Comment: `a` will always be 15 after the for loop, you need exit conditions `Exit For` in the If block.

Comment: ow. i missed that! thx!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is this, but it works. ahhaha
just add `ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlRows`
before `end sub`