# Looping code to continue making charts with different series

Tags: vba, charts

This is my first time learning and working with VBA so bear with me please.

I've worked out this makeshift code to plot xvalues vs. y values and everything's great so far (I think). Now I'd like to create something that makes a second, third, fourth (and so on) graph using data that simply needs to shift down by 4 rows. Can someone help?!

```
Sub VOCChartMaker()

    Sheets("HousevGarageCharts").Select

    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes.AddChart.Select

    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "='Data'!$C$2"

        Do Until ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count = 0
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        Loop

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "='Data'!$A$2"
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Data'!$D$2:$BB$2"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Data'!$D$3:$BB$3"
        .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 5
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "='Data'!$A$4"
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "='Data'!$D$4:$BB$4"
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='Data'!$D$5:$BB$5"
        .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerSize = 5

        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Garage"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "House"


    End With

    End With


End Sub
```

Thanks a bunch!

Megan

Comment: This has something similar to my answer for this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007443) except the series are vertical. You need add a loop to create a new chart as the range increases, so first chart has 1 series, second chart has 2 series, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing complete solution I add some key point+comments to part of your code. I think the rest will go easy after that.

```
Sub VOCChartMaker()

    Sheets("HousevGarageCharts").Select

'>> we need a simple loop which will star here
    Dim i As Byte  '>>required declaration
    For i=1 To 4   '>>for four charts

    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes.AddChart.Select

    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .HasTitle = True

        '>> title for every fourth row starting from 2nd
        .ChartTitle.Text = "='Data'!$C$" & 2 + (i-1)*4

        '>> as far as you create new chart you don't need it _
            as there is nothing to delete

        'Do Until ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count = 0
        'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        'Loop

        'changes made to create chart series for every fourth row starting from 2nd
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "='Data'!$A$" & 2 + (i-1)*4
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Data'!$D$" & 2 +  (i-1)*4 & ":$BB$" & 2 +  (i-1)*4
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Data'!$D$" & 3 +  (i-1)*4 & ":$BB$" & 3 +  (i-1)*4
        .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 5

        '>> change the second series accordingly on your own!!!!!
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "='Data'!$A$4"
            .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "='Data'!$D$4:$BB$4"
            .SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='Data'!$D$5:$BB$5"
            .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerSize = 5

        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Garage"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "House"


    End With

    End With

    Next i  '>> the end of the loop

End Sub
```